# where to configure Grails unit test logging

Tags: unit-testing, grails, logging

I'm still learning some of the Grails configuration details and I'm wondering the appropriate way to configure logging for unit testing. Right now I configure my prod, dev and test environments in Config.groovy and unit test logging in log4j.test.properties. As I understand it the test environment in Config.groovy is for integration testing.

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test environment is for any and all tests (unit, integration, functional).  So just configure your log4j in the Config.groovy within a test environment block.

Comment: What if I want to do other per environment configuration that differs between test types such as different database parameters for functional and integration testing. Should I just create custom environments?

Comment: Yes, and then use the -Dgrails.env=foo when you execute test-app